# Wordpress theme development: Posts in multiple columns using Bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a solution to display my custom post type in 4 columns using

```
row
```

and

```
.col-lg-3 .col-6
```

However I cant figure out how to make this work with PHP but I've figured out that I need some sort of counter to let the site know when to close the row and open a new one.

In my head I see it like this. Sorry if it makes zero sense...

```
counter starting at 0

echo starting row and starting col

add 1 to counter and check if its less than 4 to see if its
time for a another col or another row.

Some way to to add closing row at the right place
when there's no more posts.
```

I can't put the logic to work and I've been looking around for some tutorial or answer finding a lot of old ones that I can't get to work.

How I want it to display on large screens:

Post1, Post2, Post3, Post4

Post 5, Post6, and so on...

And on phones like this:

Post1, Post2

Post3, and so on

Maybe some wordpress dev already has the code for this to work. One can hope :)

My code at the moment:

```
<?php
$allPostsOfMyType = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC'
));

while($allPostsOfMyType->have_posts()) {
  $allPostsOfMyType->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid"<?php the_post_thumbnail(); 
?>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <p><?php the_field(fieldName); ?></p>
      <p><?php the_field(fieldNamer); ?></p>
      <p><a href="mailto:<?php the_field(fieldName); ?>"><?php 
the_field(fieldName); ?></a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying list of all posts of custom post type, it is not required to close "row" after four posts. You can continue and display all posts under single parent "row".

For example,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Post 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Post 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Post 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Post 4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Post 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Post 6</div>
</div>
```

It will display posts as you want,

Post1, Post2, Post3, Post4

Post5, Post6...so on

Please add your PHP code of custom post type loop here...I can help you with that.

Comment: Updated my post above

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $allPostsOfMyType = new WP_Query(
    array('posts_per_page'=> -1, 
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type', 
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC'));

if($allPostsOfMyType->have_posts()){ ?>

<div class="row mt-5">
    <?php while($allPostsOfMyType->have_posts()) {
      $allPostsOfMyType->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p>
            <?php the_field(fieldName); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php the_field(fieldNamer); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="mailto:<?php the_field(fieldName); ?>">
                <?php the_field(fieldName); ?>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```